# What does it mean when something "drops voltage"?

Tags: voltage

You quite often read that a part "drops voltage". What exactly does this mean?

That if there is 9V on the one side of the part, and it drops 3V, that there are only 6V left on the other?

Comment: Yes, you are essentially correct.  Your part, which could be a component or cables (basically anything with resistance) 'drops' 3 of the available 9V, leaving 6V which must be dropped across the rest of the circuit.  See my answer which attempts to explain this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a water supply and the pressure drops (due to a long small-bore pipe) then this is the same as a volt-drop but in the world of hydraulics. The pressure may be good at the feed end of the pipe but at the far end of the pipe (with a certain flow of water aka current) the pressure has dropped.

The pipe acts the same as a electrical resistor - it drops pressure just as the resistor drops voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the schematic below.  We have a 1V constant-voltage source and two series resistors.  The total circuit resistance is 300Ω, and so a current of 3mA will flow through the resistors.  Whenever current flows through a resistive component, a potential difference is developed across it.  The sum of the potential differences in a circuit equals the source potential difference.  Because of this mathematical relationship, we consider resistive components as "dropping" voltage.

In this particular example, we have 1V as available source voltage.  R1 drops 0.33V, leaving 0.66V.  The 0.66V is dropped across R2, completing the maths.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV3Gmf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Another good example is power leads.  If you have a high current load, and you use power leads to connect the load to a power supply, then you have to be careful to choose cables which are very low resistance.  This is because the resistance of the cables will 'drop' voltage.  So if you have cables which are 0.1Ω in resistance and you use them to connect a load which draws 10A, you will find that 1V is dropped across the cables! If your supply voltage was 12V, then only 11V is available to your circuit - as you eluded to in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two pictures illustrating the @Andyaka's explanation above.

[image]

[image]